# Why is ExternalEvaluate running the command Quantity[471.04`, "Kilobytes"] on RaspberryPi

Tags: units, python, external-calls, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 4B with 32 bit Raspberry Pi OS Full:
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Mathematica for Raspberry Pi 13.1

The command

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "2+2"]
```

Generates a large list of odd and seemingly unrelated warnings before finally giving the correct result:
[image]

The stack trace for the first warning has an unexpected `Quantity[471.04, "Kilobytes"]` in it.
[image]

The command `Quantity[471.04, "Kilobytes"]` by itself also causes similar warnings:
[image]